# Access method from another class No static?

Tags: java, constructor, static-methods

I had a lot of problems in my code because of static methods and variables.
I'm new to programming and I noticed when I use static in a class I can call it wherever I want.
The link below is my previous question(if you need to, its just why of trying to not use static) where someone told me to remove the static for a method which solved part of my problem.

PS: english is my 3rd language so it may be bad.
But please help me I'm stuck

[Get random object from arraylist specific variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612851/get-random-object-from-arraylist-specific-variable)

So my problem:

I have a constructor to create cars and the parameter are filled with functions.
But since the object it not yet created I can't get the methods.
Is there a way I cant call them?
Here is my code:
Right now `Cars.getPosition()` is underlined red and its telling me to make it static.

From garage class where the cars are created:

```
public void addCar() {
    Cars car = new Cars(Cars.getID(), Cars.askCarID(), Cars.getPosition(), Attendant.askForAtt(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    myGarage.add(car);
    if(!(car.getAssignedTo()).equals(null)){
        car.getAssignedTo().setAssign(car);
        car.getAssignedTo().setAvailable(false);
    }
}
```

From car class:

```
private static void createCarsID() {

    for (int x = 0; x < Garage.getCarsCapacity(); x++) {
        String tempCarID = ("CR" + (x + 1));
        tempArray2.add(tempCarID);
    }
}

public static String getID() {

    createCarsID();
    String tempID = null;
    String tempPos = null;
    for (int x = 0; x < Garage.getCarsCapacity(); x++) {
        if (tempArray2.get(x) != null) {
            tempID = tempArray2.get(x);
            tempPos = tempArray2.get(x);
            tempArray2.remove(tempArray2.get(x));
            getPos(tempPos);
            //tempArray2.get(x) = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    return tempID;
}

public void getPos(String IdToPos) {
    String strPos = IdToPos.substring(2);
    int pos = Integer.parseInt(strPos);
    position = "GR" + pos;

}
```

Comment: Your getter and setter should not be static, they are used to get or set the data on Car object (instance) not on the Car class. If you want to stream line or simplify your process of Car creation, please consider using Builder pattern. If you want to provide some random data while creating class move it outside of your Car class, like for instance make a class CarDataProvider and add these static functions there.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the ways you can do it. The new car's information is taken from the keyboard, but doesn't need to be like that.

Garage.java

```
package yourPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Víctor Bernabé Pérez
 */
public class Garage {

    private final Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    private final BufferedReader scanText = new BufferedReader(inStream);
    private final ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public Garage() {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCar() {
        try {
            System.out.print("id");
            int id = scanInt.nextInt();
            System.out.print("carId");
            int carId = scanInt.nextInt();
            System.out.print("position");
            int position = scanInt.nextInt();
            long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.print("Attendant");
            String attendant = new String();
            try {
                attendant = scanText.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Garage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            boolean free;
            String available = scanText.readLine();
            if (available.equals("s")) {
                free = true;
            } else {
                free = false;
            }

            cars.add(new Car(id, carId, position, attendant, timeMillis, free));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Garage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
package yourPackage;

/**
 *
 * @author Víctor Bernabe Pérez
 */
public class Car {

    private int id, carId, position;
    private long timeMillis;
    private String attendant;
    private boolean available;

    public Car(){
        //Nothing, just default constructor
    }

    public Car(int id, int carId, int position, String attendant, long timeMillis, boolean available){
        this.id = id;
        this.carId = carId;
        this.position = position;
        this.attendant = attendant;
        this.timeMillis = timeMillis;
        this.available = available;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I can't it has to be a string like CR1 or Pos1.

Comment: and the system should be the one giving it

Comment: You posted your code partially, so I can't see the fields of your classes or the main logic. But you can solve it, just stop trying to create an object with information that has to be returned from that object itself. I could help you with the exact solution if you post all your code.